# SignalR Websocket not receiving messages

Tags: signalr

Any ideas why the following code isn't working?

https://github.com/jerriepelser-blog/signalr-long-running

JobProgressHub.AssociateJob isn't being called. I'm running in Chrome, Window10, VS2019.

[image]

Comment: You might want to ask the original developer directly https://github.com/jerriepelser-blog/signalr-long-running/issues

Comment: You likely will not get a reply there as it has not been touched in 3 years. You should probably detail what version of SignalR Core you are using. That project uses - "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.0" and may not be completely compatible with later versions.

Comment: SignalR 1.0.1.0